# Keep lines formed with specific characters

Tags: c#, string, file, format, character

I have a text file with several lines and a list of approved characters that can be used. If there are any characters in a line that are not on the approved list, the entire line needs to be deleted.

How can I go about completing this? C# would be the ideal, but Python, PowerShell or JS would be helpful as well.

---

Example approved characters: `abcdefg`

Valid: `abc`

Invalid: `abc1`

---

For my program I want the following list of approved characters:

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890#^,;.`

After sorting the contents I want it to write them back to the file (without the invalid lines).

Comment: seems very simple and straightforward to me - what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a simple concept, but it's important that _**you**_ give it a go before posting a question here. Stackoverflow is _not_ a code-writing service, so please in the future include code you've tried prior to asking a specific question.

Comment: For each character, check if it's allowed -- if not, then delete the line. Tell us where exactly you struggle so someone can give a focused answer.

Comment: I'll try with character by character check that @hugo mentioned. So far I've tried using regex with a Powershell script that I ended up deleting because I couldn't get the correct expression for "keep the lines formed with this characters". Also tried to do the reverse in Powershell as well and eliminate the lines with any other characters, but couldn't figure out the logic for it. Thanks for the clarification btw, I'm still new to all of this but I'll keep it in mind if I ever need to post again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a program that filters out all lines that contain invalid characters where args[0] is the input file and args[1] is the output file.

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string AllowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890#^,;.";
        var lines = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
        using StreamWriter outfile = new (args[1]);
        foreach (string line in lines)
            if (line.All(x => AllowedChars.Contains(x)))
                await file.WriteLineAsync(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *Linq* in order to *query* the file:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  // HashSet<T> is more efficient than List<T> for Contains: O(1) vs. O(N)
  HashSet<char> allowed = new HashSet<char>(
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890#^,;."
  );

  string fileName = @"c:\MyFile.txt";

  var clearedLines = File
    .ReadLines(fileName)
    .Where(line => line.All(letter => allowed.Contains(letter)))
    .ToArray(); // Since we have to write back, we have to materialize the data

  File.WriteAllLines(fileName, clearedLines);
```